# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem. For some reason a horizontal scroll bar keeps appearing from my code. I've tried everything but I can't seem to remove it. The following link is a live preview of the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/y5x7V/

HTML

```
 <body>
 <section class="contain">
 <div id="section-nav" class="section-nav">
 <div class="top">
 <ul>
 <li class="logo"><a href="#">Magna Contra</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="#">Blog With Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Compxta</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Laurie</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">SUBTITLESOFLIFE</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </section>

 <div class="bg">

 <h1>SUBTITLESOFLIFE</h1>
 </div>

 <ul class="check">
 <li class="bold"><a href="#">Hot Trends</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">Daft Punk</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">#bbcqt</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">Petite Noir - Major</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">Alt J Album Teaser</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">Materialistic Happine$$</a></li>
 <li class="topic"><a href="#">WOLF</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="contar">
  Lorem Dosi
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
}

.check{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;

}




::selection{background:red;color:red;}::-moz-selection{background:red;color:red;}

li
{
display: inline;
padding:15px;
text-align: center;
margin:auto 0;
position: relative;
}

li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#bbbbbb;
  font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.78em;
letter-spacing: .2em}

hr{
  color:#dfe0db;
    border: 0;
background-color: #dfe0db;
height: 1px;
}

.bold{
  display: inline;
}

.bold a{
  color:#e94378;
}
.topic{
  display: inline;
padding:8px;
text-align: center;
margin:auto 0;
position: relative;

}

.topic a{
-webkit-transition:400ms;-moz-transition:400ms;-o-transition:400ms;transition:400ms;color:#bbb;font-weight:700;outline:0;text-decoration:none}

.topic a:hover{
  color:#e94378;text-decoration:none}

}

.logo a{
  color:#bbb;
  font-size: 0.78em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


img#hv {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}

img#hv:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
.image {position: relative; text-align: center;width:100%;height:75%;}

.image span {position: absolute; line-height: 20px; display: block; top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -10px; width: 100%; color: white;font-family: "proxima-nova";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em; letter-spacing:;}


@media screen and (max-width:800px) { 
   .image span { 
        font-size:0.8em; 
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) { 
    .image span {
        font-size:0.7em; 
    }
}



.bg{
  background-color: #e94378;
}

img.ri
 {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 width:100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 img.ri { max-width: 100%; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 img.ri { max-height: 100%; }
 }


.text{
font-family: "proxima-nova";
  font-size: 1em;
letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #e94378;
padding:20px;
color:yellow;
position: absolute;
left:200px;
bottom:50px;
}

.tex{
  font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  bottom:160px;
  left: 320px;
  color:white;
  padding: 10px;


}

.image{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo a:hover{
color:white;
}
.active a{
  color:white;
}

.contain{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.top {
  background-color: #444;
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;


}

.navigation:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #222;

}
.push {
  height: auto;
}
.contar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-color: white;


}

img.ft{
  float:left;
}
.featured{
  background-color: white;
  width:69%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;;
}
.block:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}


.search {
border:0px; 
background-color:transparent; 
color:white;
display: inline-block;
height:28px;
}

.section-nav a{-webkit-transition:400ms;-moz-transition:400ms;-o-transition:400ms;transition:400ms;color:#bbb;font-weight:700;outline:0;text-decoration:none;}
.section-nav a.active,.section-nav a:hover{color:#fff;text-decoration:none}



h1{
font: 800 1em "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
font-size:3.125em;
text-align:center;
padding:10px 10px;
margin:20px 20px;
background-color:;
position: relative;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
letter-spacing: 6px;
color:yellow;}

h1 a{
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 8px;
padding-left: 0.15em;
color:#a8a820;
}



.txt{
  font:800 proxima-nova;
}







h2{
font: 800 1em "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
font-size:3.125em;
text-align:center;
padding:10px 10px;
margin:20px 20px;
background-color:;
position: relative;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
letter-spacing: 6px;
color:yellow;}

h2 a{
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 8px;
padding-left: 0.15em;
color:#a8a820;
}
```

Comment: You have some very invalid HTML.

Comment: You do not need all those `</li>` before `<div class="contar">`

Comment: Thank you I have now removed them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `overflow-x: hidden` - it only papers over the cracks, it doesn't fix the issue. You can fix it by using the `box-sizing` property on the top div:

```
.top {
    background-color: #444;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

This takes your `padding: 10px` into account when applying 100% width.

You can also use a [polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) to check for browser support, using the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

add 
`overflow-x:hidden`

to the main wrapper class

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're combining both 100% width and padding. If 100% width evaluates to 100px, for example, adding 5px padding to the left and right on top of that will cause your element to have an overall width of 110px. You can get around this by changing the element's [`box-sizing`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

```
.bottom, .top {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5x7V/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set overflow-x in body to hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/y5x7V/1/

```
body {
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this correctly rather than hacking in some CSS to hide the scrollbar by fixing the `top` class in your CSS. Set the padding to 0 (as it's taking the full width of the parent) by adding:

`padding:0;`

to `.top`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9uj/1/)

You can set the padding's height property to get the original look, this is just a quick fix to demo why it's breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.top {padding:10px;}
```

to

```
.top {padding:10px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 261 of css you provided, change from `padding: 10px;`, to `padding: 10px 0;`.