# how to remove this thing in html?

Tags: html, css

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpBql.png)

code

```
<!-- Simple social network, named Topazz. -->

<!-- Site logic. -->
<script>
    // Post tag.
    import Post from "./Parts/Post.svelte"

    // Site pages.
    import {Pages} from "./Pages.svelte"

    // Site images.
    import {Images} from "./Parts/Images.svelte"
</script>

<!-- Site styles. -->
<style>
    div.Hat {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;

        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    img.Icon {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;

        position: relative;

        top: 5px;
    }

    span.InfoInTitle {
        color: grey;
        font-size: small;

        position: relative;
        top: -9px;
    }

    span.NameInTitle {
        position: relative;

        top: -3px;
        left: 5px;
    }

    div.Right {
        float: right;
    }

    div.AboutBlock {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;

        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    p.AboutLabel {
        position: relative;

        top: 32px;
        left: 22px;
    }

    div.TermsOfUse {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;

        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    p.TermsOfUseLabel {
        position: relative;

        top: 32px;
        left: 41px;
    }

    button.TermsOfUseButton {
        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        background-color: darkblue;
        color: white;

        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    div.CreatePostBlock {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;

        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    p.CreatePostLabel {
        position: relative;

        top: 32px;
        left: 11px;
    }

    button.CreatePostButton {
        border: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        background-color: darkblue;
        color: white;

        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
    }
</style>

<!-- Hat of site. -->
<div class="Hat">
    <!-- Title. -->
    <h1><span class="NameInTitle">Topazz Official</span> <img class="Icon" src={Images.Icon} alt="Site icon."> <span class="InfoInTitle">Anonymous forum for <i>you</i>.</span></h1>
</div>

<!-- About site block. -->
<div class="Right">
    <!-- Main block with content. -->
    <div class="AboutBlock">
        <!-- Text and button. -->
        <p class="AboutLabel">Read about our site. → <a href={Pages.About}><button class="CreatePostButton">About.</button></a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Spaces. -->
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>

<!-- Create post block. -->
<div class="Right">
    <!-- Main block with content. -->
    <div class="TermsOfUse">
        <!-- Text and button. -->
        <p class="TermsOfUseLabel">Read our TOU. → <a href={Pages.TermsOfUse}><button class="TermsOfUseButton">Create Post.</button></a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Spaces. -->
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>

<!-- Create post block. -->
<div class="Right">
    <!-- Main block with content. -->
    <div class="CreatePostBlock">
        <!-- Text and button. -->
        <p class="CreatePostLabel">Create your own post. → <a href={Pages.CreatePost}><button class="CreatePostButton">Create Post.</button></a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Spaces. -->
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

how to remove this thing that pointed by lines?
how i can remove it?

Comment: When the site is prompting you to add an explanation, that is not an indication that you should enter a bunch of filler text to get around this restriction. Please add a detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you mean the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to pare your code down to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unwanted horizontal scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044672/unwanted-horizontal-scroll-bar)

Comment: Maybe you should find another way for your `div.Right`. When you remove the `float`, it won't scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    :global(html, body) {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

solved

Comment: What is :global?

Comment: i am using svelte

Answer (score 0):

That scrollbar appears when your page is wider then your window, you should ispect your website in your browser (In most browsers F12, or right click -> Inspect) to see wich element is wider then your screen and fix its with